# Create a directory with sys_mkdir. Directories end with?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm learning assembly (NASM) and using the Linux system calls.

I'm having a problem with the following code. I am attempting to call `sys_mkdir`. A directory "Hello World" should be created. But, instead it's creating the following `Hello World?asmtest??`. Why is this? How is the `title` being included and how do I remove the `?`.

```
SECTION .data
msg:    db "Hello World", 10
len:    equ $-msg

title: db "asmtest", 7
mode:   dd 755

SECTION .text
global main

main:
    ; Make a directory            
    mov ecx,mode
    mov ebx,msg
    mov eax,39
    int 0x80

    ; Print Hello World to screen
    mov edx,len
    mov ecx,msg
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,4
    int 0x80

    ; Exit
    mov ebx,0
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Strings end at a zero byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the function call that you are accessing is a system call.  While it's not part of the C standard library, the handling of strings in this call (and many like it) are very "C like", meaning that byte strings are *always* null terminated.

In your case, since you define two strings (with some special characters in between, like "10" and "7"), it will use everything from the very first character found at the memory location that `msg` points to and keep going until it happens to find a null byte (`00`).

If you replace your `, 10` with `, 0` the `sys_mkdir` will function properly, but you will have to adjust that byte for your print function to work properly.

Comment: FYI, he is not accessing a C library here, that's a direct system call.

Comment: True...  I'll modify it.. Would you agree that, while it's not the C library, all of the C calling conventions for handling a string apply here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "all", but yeah, this syscall expects a zero terminated string.

Comment: Well, check the edit.  :)  I misstated it the first time through, but I think this is accurate.

Comment: Yeah, looks good. Note that simply replacing the `10` with `0` breaks the following `write` call, since then that will include the null character instead of a line feed. But I guess that's clear for OP too.

Comment: Oops!  Didn't notice the print.. I was focused on the mkdir.

Comment: The `?` comes from `ls` representing unprintable characters with a `?`.